# Add/delete rows to and from a many-to-many relationship in JPA provided by EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

Copy & paste some introductory part from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19830910/1391249).

I'm using JPA 2.0 in EclipseLink 2.3.2 in which I have a many-to-many relationship between products and their colours. A product can have many colours and a colour can be associated with many products. This relationship is expressed in the database by three tables.

- product
- prod_colour (join table)
- colour

The `prod_colour` table has two reference columns `prod_id` and `colour_id` from its related parent tables `product` and `colour` respectively.

As obvious, the entity class `Product` has a set of colours - `java.util.Set<Colour>` which is named `colourSet`.

The entity class `Colour` has a set of products - `java.util.Set<Product>` which is named `productSet`.

---

To add and delete rows to and from the `prod_colour` table, I have defined two methods in the `Colour` entity class itself as follows.

```
public void addToProduct(Product product) {
    this.getProductSet().add(product);
    product.getColourSet().add(this);
}

public void removeFromProduct(Product product) {
    this.getProductSet().remove(product);
    product.getColourSet().remove(this);
}
```

These methods are called from an EJB as follows.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void insert(List<Colour> colours, Product product) {
    for (Colour colour : colours) {
        colour.addToProduct(product);
    }
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void delete(Colour colour, Product product) {
    colour.removeFromProduct(product);
}
```

I expect them to add and delete rows to and from the `prod_colour` table but nothing happens (no error, no exception is caused). The same thing works in Hibernate. So, what else is missing here?

---

**EDIT:**

The `Product` entity class:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "prod_id")
    private Long prodId;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JoinTable(name = "prod_colour", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "prod_id")},
                    inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "colour_id", referencedColumnName = "colour_id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Colour> colourSet;

    //Getters and Setters.
}
```

The `Colour` entity class.

```
public class Colour implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "colour_id")
    private Long colourId;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "colourSet", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

    private Set<Product> productSet;

    //Setters and getters.
}
```

Comment: Yes both of them don't work (no error, no exception is caused).

Comment: Are you sure, you check the right table? Have you checked the DB query log? Do you do also a merge with `entityManager.merge(colour)` eventually also with the product?

Comment: Yes this doesn't generate any `DELETE` or `INSERT` statement (I have enabled debugging in the `presistence.xml` file).

Comment: What about the merge/save of the entities in DB with `entityManager.merge(colour)`?

Comment: With `entityManager.merge(colour)`, changes are saved to the `colour` table itself which should be made to the `prod_colour` table - join table.

Comment: :) well, I think it is time for you to show me your entities, to see how they are mapped, but you MUST definitely save either the colour, or product. Saving the colour, almost sure means saving in both tables.

Comment: Edited to include the entity classes.

Comment: OK, in order to update that join table, you need e.g fully/eagerly loaded entities and after you code, do not forget to call the entityManager.merge(colour); & entityManager.merge(product); Also I think you need a book or some good tutorials in order to understand how ManyTo* relationships & the fetchtype works.

Comment: With these changes, both the operations `INSERT` (`FetchType.EAGER`, `entityManager.merge(colour);entityManager.merge(product);`) and `DELETE` (don't require `entityManager.remove(colour);entityManager.remove(product);`) now work as they should. May put this as an answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update that join table, you need e.g fully/eagerly loaded entities and after you code, do not forget to call:

```
entityManager.merge(colour);
entityManager.merge(product);
```

Comment: Like Hibernate, lazy fetch in a many-to-many relationship also works for updating (and all other) operations in [EclipseLink 2.5.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.1/eclipselink-2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5.zip). Not quite enough sure about the version, in addition to updating EclipseLink, I have also changed `java.util.Set` to `java.util.List` everywhere in the application and made a few other changes. These changes may be a discrepancy. It happened almost all accidently and I could not find the exact reason how and when lazy fetch started working.