# org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, jpa-2.0, criteria

I have a many-to-many relationship in JPA 2.0 provided by <s>Hibernate 4.2.0 CR1</s> (recently upgraded to Hibernate 4.2.7 final) between `Product` and `Colour` as follows.

The `Product` entity class:

```
public class Product implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "prod_id")
    private Long prodId;

    @JoinTable(name = "prod_colour", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "prod_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "colour_id", referencedColumnName = "colour_id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    private Set<Colour> colourSet;

    //Setters and getters.
}
```

The `Colour` entity class.

```
public class Colour implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "colour_id")
    private Long colourId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "colourSet", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    private Set<Product> productSet;

    //Setters and getters.
}
```

To fetch a list of colours from the `colour` table based on `prodId` supplied which does not match the colours in the `prod_colour` table (join table), I'm executing the following criteria query.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Colour>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Colour.class);
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Colour> entityType = metamodel.entity(Colour.class);
Root<Colour> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
criteriaQuery.select(root);

Subquery<Long>subquery=criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Product> subRoot = subquery.from(Product.class);
subquery.select(root.get(Colour_.colourId));

Predicate paramPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get(Product_.prodId), prodId);
Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Colour_.productSet), subRoot);

subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(paramPredicate, correlatePredicate));
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get(Colour_.colourId)).value(subquery).not());

criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Colour_.colourId)));
TypedQuery<Colour> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Colour>list=typedQuery.getResultList();
```

This criteria query causes the following exception to be thrown.

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a
>   binary logic operator were incompatibile
>   [java.util.Set(model.Colour.productSet) : model.Product]

The following JPQL however works.

```
FROM Colour colour 
WHERE colour.colourId 
NOT IN(
SELECT colours.colourId 
     FROM Product product 
     INNER JOIN product.colourSet colours 
     WHERE product.prodId=:id) 
ORDER BY colour.colourId DESC
```

What is the cause of this exception. How to make this criteria query work? This same criteria [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861861/1391249) somehow works in JPA provided by EclipseLink.

---

The stacktrace :

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/admin_side/ProductColour.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /admin_side/ProductColour.xhtml @28,121 rendered="#{not empty productColourManagedBean.colourList}": Error reading 'colourList' on type admin.mangedbean.ProductColourManagedBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'colourList' on type admin.mangedbean.ProductColourManagedBean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:47)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [java.util.Set(model.Colour.productSet) : model.Product]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:587)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at $Proxy98.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at admin.dao.ProductColourDAO.getList(ProductColourDAO.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy120.getList(Unknown Source)
    at admin.mangedbean.ProductColourManagedBean.getColourList(ProductColourManagedBean.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [java.util.Set(model.Colour.productSet) : model.Product]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.mutateRowValueConstructorSyntaxesIfNecessary(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.initialize(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.prepareLogicOperator(HqlSqlWalker.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4371)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2076)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2004)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4644)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4347)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2076)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2051)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1734)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:452)
    ... 119 more
```

Anyway, the **criteria query** should fetch a list of colours from the `colour` table based on `prodId` supplied which does not match the colours in the `prod_colour` table (It could be a join query, a subquery or anything else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following criteria query works perfectly as expected.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Colour> entityType = metamodel.entity(Colour.class);
Root<Colour> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(Colour_.colourId), root.get(Colour_.colourName), root.get(Colour_.colourHex));

Subquery<Long>subquery=criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Colour> subRoot = subquery.from(Colour.class);
subquery.select(subRoot.get(Colour_.colourId));
SetJoin<Colour, Product> join = subRoot.join(Colour_.productSet, JoinType.INNER);

ParameterExpression<Long> parameterExpression=criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get(Colour_.colourId)).value(subquery).not());
subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(Product_.prodId), parameterExpression));

TypedQuery<Tuple> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Tuple> list = typedQuery.setParameter(parameterExpression, 1L).getResultList();
```

Resulting in the following SQL query.

```
select
    colour0_.colour_id as col_0_0_,
    colour0_.colour_name as col_1_0_,
    colour0_.colour_hex as col_2_0_ 
from
    social_networking.colour colour0_ 
where
    colour0_.colour_id not in  (
        select
            colour1_.colour_id 
        from
            social_networking.colour colour1_ 
        inner join
            prod_colour productset2_ 
                on colour1_.colour_id=productset2_.colour_id 
        inner join
            social_networking.product product3_ 
                on productset2_.prod_id=product3_.prod_id 
        where
            product3_.prod_id=?
    )
```

Although it is a `Tuple` query, one may execute the same query on an entity. In my case, only a `Tuple` query is sufficient.

Comment: what's the Colour_ meaning here?

Comment: @ZengSN : It is a static [Metamodel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html) class in which every property that corresponds to a property in its corresponding entity (POJO) is declared `public static volatile` that allows us to write type safe criteria queries. Thus, instead of writing, `root.get("colourId")` which can only be resolved dynamically at run time, if it is rewritten just like `root.get(Colour_.colourId))` then, it is resolved at compile-time itself. Different ORM frameworks have [different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3037817/1391249) Metamodel generators.

Comment: [This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-typesafejpa/) is a nice article about type safe queries.